# How can i change the camera view when clicking a button?

Tags: unity, c#

I added enum with all the views options.
But when i click/press on V nothing happen with the game is running.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowTargetCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum Views
    {
        Forward, Backward, Left, Right
    }

    public Transform Target;
    public float PositionFolowForce = 5f;
    public float RotationFolowForce = 5f;

    public Views views;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 vector = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        Vector3 dir = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
        {
            switch (views)
            {
                case Views.Backward:
                    vector = Vector3.back;
                    dir = Target.rotation * Vector3.back;
                    break;
                case Views.Forward:
                    vector = Vector3.forward;
                    dir = Target.rotation * Vector3.forward;
                    break;
                case Views.Left:
                    vector = Vector3.left;
                    dir = Target.rotation * Vector3.left;
                    break;
                case Views.Right:
                    vector = Vector3.right;
                    dir = Target.rotation * Vector3.right;
                    break;
            }
        }
        dir.y = 0f;
        if (dir.magnitude > 0f) vector = dir / dir.magnitude;

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, Target.position, PositionFolowForce * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(vector), RotationFolowForce * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not initialising _views_ variable, the code will not fall into any cases of your switch statement.

Comment: A not-initialized enum equals 0, thar's not the problem

Comment: Fixed Update is no the place you want to check Input. Try it in Update

Answer (score 1):

You don't change the value of variable `views` anywhere (in the given code), that's why it doesn't change.

It will be Views.Backward all the time, for example.

If you want it to be looping through all the views, you could try something like

```
if (views < 3 ) ++views
else views = 0
```

This can be achieved in more optimal ways, but check if that simply works.